# how to sort items in array by one specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have an array with an items and every item have few values.
I need to sort items in the array by value 'level' and than i need to echo some piece of code for every item.

Database looks something like this.

```
$database= [
[
'name'=> 'item_one',
'preview_href'=> 'item_one.php',
'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
'level'=> 5.9,
'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
[
'name'=> 'item_two',
'preview_href'=> 'item_two.php';
'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
'level'=> 7.5,
'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
  ],
 ];
```

I have tried something like this but it didnt work.

```
function top_items($two)
{
  $two= arsort($two);

     foreach (array_slice($two, 0, 20) as $one)
    {
        echo '<div class="item">
        <a href="'. $one['preview_href'].'">
       <img src="' . $one['img_src'] .'">
       <p> '.$one['name'].' (' . $one['release']. ') </p>
          </a>
       </div>';
     }

   };
```

my expected output: I need to use this code for first 20 or whatever number of items with biggest ['level'] value:

```
        echo '<div class="item">
        <a href="'. $one['preview_href'].'">
        <img src="' . $one['img_src'] .'">
        <p> '.$one['name'].' (' . $one['release']. ') </p>
       </a>
       </div>';
```

$one is an one item(array) in a big array database. In big database i have all of the items.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this to sort subarray by value:

In <= PHP 5.6:

```
usort($database, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['level'] - $b['level'];
});
```

In >= PHP 7.0:

```
usort($database, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['level'] <=> $b['level'];
});
```

Then get first 20 items (can replace 20 by x number):

```
$output = array_slice($database, 0, 20);
```

Comment: i had to change it little bit for something like this:             
 
    usort($database, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['level'] > $a['level'];
But it works....thanks a lot